# SphinxQL query builder - how to add multiple and/or operators to match

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxql

this is my query:

```
$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('*')
    ->from('my_index')
    ->match('name', 'bird + monkey', true);
    $result = $query->execute();
```

adding `+` or `||` between values works (giving results that match 'bird' and/or 'monkey').

I would like to add more than one operator, something like this:

```
    $query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('*')
    ->from('my_index')
    ->match('name', '(bird + monkey) || cat', true);
    $result = $query->execute();
```

I tried looking in the [Query Builder for SphinxQL](https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder)  and [sphinxsearch documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/10/20/sphinxql-query-builder-for-php/) but couldn't find such an example.

Comment: Try this .. if this not working let me know .....   $where = "name LIKE '%(bird + monkey)%' OR name LIKE '%cat%'";
$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('*')
                ->from('my_index')
                ->match($where);
$result = $query->execute();

Comment: @KumarRakesh thanks, but it doesn't recognize the word 'LIKE', just gives an empty result.  only works like this: `$where = "name '%bird%'";` with no operators.

Comment: Where did `+` and `||` come from? Neither are Sphinx operators!

Comment: The real operators are here: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

Comment: @barryhunter, thank you, I was actually using the wrong operators.  this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to barryhunter.
the right syntax is:

```
 $query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('*')
->from('my_index')
->match('name', '("bird  monkey") | cat', true);
$result = $query->execute();
```